# Term for an anti-theft/anti-loss feature seen on pens

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

I suspect many people here have seen those pens in banks by the tellers, that have lines between them and the counter top, so users can't walk off with them. I am trying to find out what that kind of option is called generally, so that I can try and extend its use to other things intelligently.

UPDATE:

I am looking for the industry standard term for these things so I can search for a similarly accoutered pocket lighter. I have a cousin who is becoming senile and do not want him to lose his lighter, or have someone steal it.

Comment: Do you have an example sentence where you would use the word? The name for the thing that prevents pens from being stolen might not work if you're trying to refer to something else.

Comment: I would call it a "chain".

Comment: "Idiot cord" is one generic reference. It applies to a variety of securing methods intended to stop you from loosing stuff. [Croakies](https://www.google.com/search?q=craokies&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&oq=craokies&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3021j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are idiot cords. I made [idiot cords](https://www.summitpost.org/phpBB3/do-you-use-the-idiot-cords-on-your-gloves-t62019.html) for my mountaineering gloves. This might fail the "intelligently" part of the question, though.

Comment: You could call it a frill, an incidental or unimportant feature that's there just its own sake, however it's often ornamental. But, in your case the string attached to the pen has a supposedly non-trivial function to stop people taking the pens, so it's not just a feature that doesn't do anything. As unimportant as the stealing of pens may be, and as unsophisticated as attaching a string to a pen is, and as ridiculous as referring to a piece of string as a "device" is, technically it would be a security device, I think.

Comment: You could call it a ***leash***

Comment: There used to be 'chained libraries'  centuries ago when books were rare and expensive, so I suppose you could call them 'chained pens'!

Comment: "PEN LEASH - COUNTER PEN" https://www.amazon.com/ORIGINAL-PEN-LEASH-COUNTER-PARACORD/dp/B00ZMCMXQU

Comment: This? https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71VkPfyKNhL._SL1280_.jpg

Comment: Tethered pens. Phone books in public phone booths were attached to the phone to prevent theft.

Comment: For the question behind the question, [Lighter Leash](http://www.lighterleash.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **tethered** pen would likely work.

tether  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tether)

> A rope, chain, cable, or other line for restraining or securing an
>   object

[image]

Comment: Although @Laurel gave a good example, I have to go with this one since Office Depot's name is a little too vague. I wish I could give you both acceptances.

Answer (score 4):

Not all bank pens use this specific type of cord, but a lot do:

> [image]

[Office Depot](https://www.officedepot.com/a/products/367751/SKILCRAFT-Chain-Pen-With-Holder-And/) sells the above pen under the name "chain pen", however the chain itself is often called either a "bead chain" (after [the manufacturer](http://www.beadchain.com/)?) or a "ball chain" (after [a different manufacturer](https://www.ballchain.com/)?) or a "ball bead chain" (splitting the difference?).

Any one of these expressions brings up different sites selling, for example, chains for dog tag necklaces, which you could attach to a lighter with a keychain.

It's also relevant to note that *bead chain* is in [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bead%20chain):

> a chain formed of small hollow metal spheres connected by short dumbbell-shaped metal links that is used especially in electric pull sockets and switches

Comment: It's called *a bead chain* or *a ball chain* because it consists of small metal beads (balls, spheres), connected via short lengths of wire. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_chain

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about pens or lighters, but many electronic devices are equipped with a ***[security slot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot)*** (sometimes called *[security port](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/382708?answerId=382708021#382708021)* or *[security anchor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot#cite_note-KryptonitePatents-1)*) to prevent their theft.

> The system consists of a small, metal-reinforced hole found commonly
>   on small or portable computers and electronics equipment such as
>   laptops, computer monitors, desktop computers, gaming consoles, and
>   video projectors, combined with a metal anchor attached to a
>   rubberized metal cable secured with a key or combination lock. The end
>   of the cable has a small loop that allows the cable to be looped
>   around a permanent object, such as a heavy table or other similar
>   equipment.
>
> The hole is found in most laptops, although a lock for it is typically
>   not included.